# WinError 2 - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess, pyodbc

I am struggling with pretty common error that says that the system cannot find the file specified.
I am using anaconda, have activated the environment and everything else seems to work fine.

I have a Microsoft Access Database that I want to connect to and export the content to pandas data frame. I decided to use pandas_access, but it does not really matter what i do I get the same error.

Have already checked if the file is there and if i have the rights to open it and everything seems to be fine.

```
import pandas_access
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

#Path to files
rig_data = r'C:/Users/e211816/OneDrive - WFT/Desktop/Kvitebjørn FF Calibration/Data/xyz.accdb'
icon_data = 'C:/Users/e211816/OneDrive - WFT/Desktop/Kvitebjørn FF Calibration/Data/icon.mdb'

#Check if file are in the directory and if you have read/write privitliges
def check_file(path):
    file = str(path.split('/')[-1])
    
    if os.access(path, os.F_OK): print('File ' + file + ' exists.')
    if os.access(path, os.R_OK): print('You have a right to read the file.')
    if os.access(path, os.W_OK): print('You have a right to write the file.')
    
    print()
        
check_file(rig_data)
check_file(icon_data)

pandas_access.list_tables(rig_data)
```

The error I receive:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-389e87138e44> in <module>
----> 1 pandas_access.list_tables(rig_data)

C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_access\__init__.py in list_tables(rdb_file, encoding)
     23     :return: A list of the tables in a given database.
     24     """
---> 25     tables = subprocess.check_output(['mdb-tables', rdb_file]).decode(encoding)
     26     return tables.strip().split(" ")
     27 

C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    413         kwargs['input'] = empty
    414 
--> 415     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    416                **kwargs).stdout
    417 

C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    491         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
    492 
--> 493     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    494         try:
    495             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    856                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    860                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1309             # Start the process
   1310             try:
-> 1311                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1312                                          # no special security
   1313                                          None, None,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. xyz.accdb is an empty database created just for debugging.

Comment: pandas_access depends on mdb_tools. Do you have mdb_tools installed on your Windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've installed mdbtools and then pandas_access. Have tried to access database with pyodbc, but I'm getting an error too.